# :[SYNTH 8-944] 0 definitions of operator sll and srr

Tags: vhdl

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
 --use IEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL; --tried with this package aslo 

architecture Behavioral of my_code is

  signal DATA: signed(31 downto 0);  
  signal DATA_OUT signed(31 downto 0); 
  signal f: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

begin

   DATA_OUT<=DATA srl  (( f-1)  sll '1');

end behavioral;
```

This is a small part of my code. I am using vivado 2018.2 .for the above line I am getting [synth 8-944] 0 definition of all operators.

I know Verilog but I am new to VHDL. should I use any other packages for that?

Please help me by providing a solution or "equivalent function" for that.

Comment: std_logic_arith and std_logic_unsigned are non-standard VHDL packages. numeric_std is the standard and contains `srl` and `sll` for signed/unsigned type.

Comment: I tried with NUMERIC_STD_.ALL package also .still no result. could you give equivalent function for that line of code please.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because there are no `sll` and `srl` operators defined for the combination of types you are using. There are operators with *signatures*:

```
[unsigned, integer, return unsigned]
[signed, integer, return signed]
```

`unsigned` and `signed` are types in the `numeric_std` package. Neither of these operators is defined for a `std_logic_vector` in any standard package. (`STD_LOGIC_ARITH`  and `STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED` are non-standard. Don't use them.)

So, you have two choices:

i) (not recommended) convert all of your types so they fit either of the above signatures or

ii) (recommended) don't use the `sll` or `srl` operators. They are badly defined and can lead to more logic being synthesised than you need. Instead, use other VHDL operators (eg *slicing*/*concatenation* or mathematical). You're trying to do maths here, so I would perhaps use mathematical operators. You'll still need to use the `numeric_std` package, because you are doing maths. You can't do maths on `std_logic_vector` unless you use a non-standard package.

Comment: I don't recommend the shift operators either, however, the logical shifts should be ok.   In addition, with VHDL-2008 and numeric_std/numeric_std_unsigned, the arithmetic ones are defined with their normal meaning.   It would be nice if you show an example of shifting with concatenation.